# Turning a pandas column/series into multiple series

Tags: python, pandas

I feel like I should be using a pivot_table here, but I can't seem to get it to work the way I want it to.  Here is the data (note: it's a subset of the data):

```
    sample_code analyte  abundance_ppm
0   85GMC-RM001      Au          0.000
1   85GMC-RM001      Bi          0.000
2   85GMC-RM001      Ag          0.400
3   85GMC-RM001      Cu         62.000
4   85GMC-RM001      Pb          7.000
5   85GMC-RM001      Zn         84.000
6   85GMC-RM001      Co         20.000
7   85GMC-RM001      Ni         11.000
8   85GMC-RM001      Mo          0.000
9   85GMC-RM001      Mn        585.000
10  85GMC-RM001      Cd          0.000
11  85GMC-RM001      Fe      63300.000
12  85GMC-RM001      Hg          0.575
13  85GMC-RM001      As          0.000
14  85GMC-RM001      Sb          0.000
15  85GMC-RM002      Au          0.000
16  85GMC-RM002      Bi          0.000
17  85GMC-RM002      Ag          0.500
18  85GMC-RM002      Cu         14.000
19  85GMC-RM002      Pb         14.000
```

I'd like to *tidy* the data, so that I have one occurrence of each sample_code, and turn the analyte feature into multiple features of each element. I've tried a pivot_table, but it makes everything extremely messy (I could be doing it wrong).  There is other data in this dataframe, but it's all unique to each sample_code.  The analyte column is what is expanding the length of the dataframe.

I worked on this half the day yesterday, and really need to move on. I feel like this is simpler than I'm making it out to be!

Comment: Something like this? `df.pivot('sample_code', 'analyte', 'abundance_ppm')` ?

Answer (score -1):

Update,

```
df.pivot_table('abundance_ppm', 'sample_code', 'analyte', aggfunc='sum')
# Pick you're aggfunc. 'sum', 'mean', 'first'.
```

Output:

```
analyte  sample_code   Ag   As   Au   Bi   Cd    Co    Cu       Fe     Hg     Mn   Mo    Ni    Pb   Sb    Zn
0        85GMC-RM001  0.4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  20.0  62.0  63300.0  0.575  585.0  0.0  11.0   7.0  0.0  84.0
1        85GMC-RM002  0.5  NaN  0.0  0.0  NaN   NaN  14.0      NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN  14.0  NaN   NaN
```

IIUC, try:

```
df.pivot('sample_code', 'analyte', 'abundance_ppm').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
analyte  sample_code   Ag   As   Au   Bi   Cd    Co    Cu       Fe     Hg     Mn   Mo    Ni    Pb   Sb    Zn
0        85GMC-RM001  0.4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  20.0  62.0  63300.0  0.575  585.0  0.0  11.0   7.0  0.0  84.0
1        85GMC-RM002  0.5  NaN  0.0  0.0  NaN   NaN  14.0      NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN  14.0  NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's exactly what I wanted.  I was using the pivot_table method, not the pivot method.